# How to correctly Parse out Text From HTML(from word)

Tags: html, asp.net, regex

This is for PHP and the input are sometimes just plain text with linebreaks
sometimes simple html with br and p tags

sometimes it gets really messing with all the mumble jumbo that msword comes with...
right now i use a a few if statements and html encode before my regex replace functions starts
to happen. final result is clean EXCEPT it removed my original user input linebreaks !

here is a sample of what the mess comes in as

```
<!--
[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:DocumentProperties>
  <o:Author>dbb</o:Author>
  <o:Version>12.00</o:Version>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:TargetScreenSize>1024x768</o:TargetScreenSize>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]
-->

<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify;mso-pagination:none">Linda S. Agnew is a partner in the Firm’s <a href="http://www.jaspanllp.com/practice-group/15/litigation">Litigation Practice Group</a> and its Appellate Practice Group. She has extensive experience in trial and appellate advocacy with an emphasis in commercial litigation and title insurance defense claims. Ms. Agnew has handled numerous complex commercial litigation matters including land use, corporate dissolution, shareholder derivative actions and litigation involving real property.  She also has substantial experience in municipal law and land use. </p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify;mso-pagination:none">Ms. Agnew co-authored the updated Chapter 17 of the Real Estate Titles treatise published by the New York State Bar Association in 2007 entitled "Adverse Possession.”  She presently serves on the Board of Directors of the National Association of Women Business Owners, Long Island Chapter, and is active in her church.  Ms. Agnew was a recipient of the 2008 Public Service Attorney of the Year Award presented by the Touro College Jacob D. Fuchsberg Law Center as well as a recipient of the 2009 Long Island Business News 40 under 40 award.   </p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify;mso-pagination:none">Ms. Agnew received her Juris Doctor from St. John's University School of Law and her Bachelor of Arts, magna cum laude, from Long Island University. During law school, Ms. Agnew was a senior member of the Moot Court Honor Society where she competed in several State and National Moot Court Competitions. She also interned with New York City’s Corporation Counsel where she was assigned to the Civil Torts Division.  <br />
   </p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify;mso-pagination:none">Ms. Agnew is admitted to practice law in the State Courts of New York and New Jersey, the United States Court of Appeals for the Second Circuit and the United States District Courts for the Eastern and Southern Districts of New York and the District of New Jersey. She is a member of the New York State Bar Association (Real Property Law Section), the Nassau County Bar Association, the Suffolk County Bar Association and the Nassau County Women’s Bar Association</p>
<!--
[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Normal</w:View>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:TrackMoves/>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
```

and here is a simple that parse and replaces for this CASE

```
bio = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(teammember.bio, "<!--(.|\n)*?-->", string.Empty));
                    if ( bio.Contains("<p")){
                        bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"\r|\n|<p(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
                        bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"</p(.)*?>", "\r\n\r\n");
                        } else {
                        bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"\r|\n", string.Empty);
                        bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"<br(.)*?>", "\r\n");
                        }
                    bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"<li(.)*?>", "• ");
                    bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"</li(.)*?>", "\r\n");
                    bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

AND This is my Current Output

> Linda S. Agnewis a partner in the Firm’s Litigation Practice Group and its
>   Appellate Practice Group. She has **extensiveexperience** in trial and
>   appellate advocacy with an emphasis in **commerciallitigation** and title
>   insurance defense claims. Ms. Agnew has handled **numerouscomplex**
>   commercial litigation matters including land use, **corporatedissolution**,
>   shareholder derivative actions and litigation involving **realproperty**. She
>   also has **substantialexperience** in municipal law and land use.

please take note at the BOLD words

Comment: "*correctly*" and regex don't go too well in the case of HTML. Use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: wops sorry this was .net not php. fixed mistake

Comment: I'm not fond of the `Contains("<p")` bit. What about HTML sources that contain `<param>` or `<pre>`?

Comment: all html is removed plus i can assume this is copied from a word doc using dum down htmls. but yes it is a bad way to program it..

Comment: Update i found my source of error to be at "bio = Regex.Replace( bio ,"\r|\n", string.Empty);" is remove linebreaks that i don't even see in the database..